# Cumulative Density Function for max minus min

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function

I originally found this question [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Probability/ARMLC_2016_7.shtml).

We pick three random numbers $x,y,z$ independently from the uniform distribution $U(0,1)$. What is the probability $\max(x,y,z)-\min(x,y,z)\le\frac{2}{3}$?

I know there are several solutions, e.g. one using geometry, and one using direct integration. However, I am curious specifically with one of the approaches suggested also in the above link. The approach is to, say, define a random variable $w\triangleq \max(x,y,z)-\min(x,y,z)$ and find the cumulative density for $w$. To do so, my approach would be:
$$F_w(w)=6\int_{x=0}^1\int_{z=\max(0,x-w)}^x\int_{y=z}^x1dydzdx=6\left(\int_{x=0}^w\int_{z=0}^x
\int_{y=z}^x1dydzdx+\int_{x=w}^1\int_{z=x-w}^x\int_{y=z}^x1dydzdx\right)=6\left(\frac{w^2}{2}-\frac{w^3}{3}\right)=3w^2-2w^3$$

Note we multiply by 6 because of permutations of $(x,y,z)$. However, the "Expanded Solution 3" in the link suggestions you can simply compute the probability density of $y$ with $x\geq y\geq z$ holding
$$f_y(x\geq y\geq z)=\int_y^1\int_0^y1dzdx=y-y^2$$
and then integrate this from $0$ to $w$ to get the desired cumulative density $F_w(w)$
$$\int_{0}^wf_y(x\geq y\geq z)=\int_{0}^w (y-y^2)dy=\frac{w^2}{2}-\frac{w^3}{3}$$
Multiplying by 6 to account for permutations gives the same expression I derived.

Can someone explain why this "shortcut" works? It's not obvious to me why integrating this probability density for $y$ from $0$ to $w$ would give the desired cumulative density, as this $f_y$ has nothing to do with the max minus min, no? I'm probably missing something simple, but any insights would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If $X$ and $Z$ are independent uniform, then the quantity $y-y^2$ is $P(X \ge y \ge Z)$ for some fixed number $y \in [0,1]$. I would not call this a "marginal density" or "marginal distribution" of the middle random variable, so I am also unclear on what $\int_0^w P(X \ge y \ge Z) \, dy$ has to do with "max minus min". The author of "Expanded solution 3" seems not very rigorous: there is a typo in Approach 1 (factor of $6$ missing), and in Approach 2 they justify a claim with "Why? I don't know exactly, but snaps out immediately." But maybe I am not smart enough to see what they see.

Comment: Yes, it's not well written and I also cannot follow their line of reasoning. However it is quite intriguing that they get the correct cumulative density function in the end, so it seems there's something going on which I'm missing.

Comment: It seems use the fact that for ordered uniform, the distribution of the differences of two order statistics is the same as long as their differences of the rank is the same. In this case the sample range $U_{(3)} - U_{(1)}$ has the same distribution of $U_{(2)} - U_{(0)}$ where $U_{(0)}$ is defined as the constant $0$. So they just compute the distribution of $U_{(2)}$ in this case and claim that is the distribution of the sample range.

Comment: Ah, that's clever. Thanks!

Comment: @BGM : If your comment answered the question, you should post an answer. In general, question-and-answer pages should be "self-contained" in that they should not require reading comments for essential information.

Comment: @BGM Is there a slick proof for your fact about differences of order statistics?

Comment: I think I have seen this in one of the recent post. Consider there is a circle with the length of the circumference equals to $1$. We randomly (uniformly) select $n+1$ points on the circle. And WLOG we can randomly pick $1$ of the point and cut the circle at that point, and transform that into a straight line with length $1$, and consider that as the $[0, 1]$ interval. Excluding the point we chosen to cut (which locate at $0$ or $1$ in the resulting interval), the remaining $n$ points form $n$ uniform (ordered) statistics. Then the result should follow from the symmetric argument.